# Is there a best practice for storing data for a database object (model) that will change or be deleted in the future (Django)?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database, database-design

I am building an order management system for an online store and would like to store information about the Product being ordered.

If I use a Foreign Key relationship to the Product, when someone changes the price, brand, supplier etc. of the Product or deletes it, the Order will be affected as well. I want the order management system to be able to display the state of the Product when it was ordered even if it is altered or deleted from the database afterwards.

I have thought about it long and hard and have come up with ideas such as storing a JSON string representation of the object; creating a duplicate Product whose foreign key I then use for the Order etc. However, I was wondering if there is a best practice or what other people use to handle this kind of situation in commercial software?

PS: I also have other slightly more complex situations, for instance, I would like the data for a User object attached to the Order to change as the User changes but then never get deleted when the User is deleted. An answer to the above question would definitely give me a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This price-change problem is commonly handled in RDBMS (SQL) commerce applications by doing two things.

1. inserting rows into an `order_detail` table when an order is placed. Each row of that table contains the particulars of the item as sold: item_id, item_count, unit_price, total_price, unit_weight, total_weight, tax_status, and so forth. So, the app captures what actually was sold, and at what price. A later price change doesn't mess up sales records.  You really have to do this.
2. a `price` table containing item_id, price, start_time, end_time. You retrieve the current price something like this:

   ```
   SELECT item.item, price.price
     FROM item
     JOIN price ON item.item = price.item
               AND price.start_date <= NOW()
               AND (price.end_date > NOW() OR price.end_date IS NULL)
   ```

   This approach allows you to keep track of historical prices, and also to set up future price changes. But you still copy the price into the `order_detail` table.

The point is: once you've accepted an order, its details cannot change in the future. You copy the actual customer data (name, shipping address, etc) into a separate `order` table from your current customer table when you accept the order, and (as mentioned above) the details of each item into an `order_detail` table.

Your auditors will hate you if you don't do this. Ask me how I know that sometime.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I guess I would opt for the first solution because I'm worried about more than just the price attribute. The admin could potentially change the brand, color, supplier, discounted_price and so many other attributes. Would you completely advise against creating a duplicate object perhaps in a ProductHistory table used only for history purposes when the order is made? I'm not sure to what extent that create would impact performance.

Comment: I suggest you do BOTH things in my answer, not just one of them.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I somehow thought 'doing one of two things'. Ok thank you very much, I think I can proceed more confidently then. (First time building commercial software with little experience outside the Computer Science classes).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating attributes for the Order model and extracting the data you need one by one into those attributes while you are saving the model and then implementing a historical data table where you store JSONFields or some other version of the Product etc. when it is created or updated; that way people can refer to the historical data table if need be. This would be more efficient usage than storing the full fledged representation of the Product in the Order object as time taken to create the historical data is essentially charged to the admin creating the Product rather than the customer creating the Order. You can even create historical data objects in the background using threads etc. when you get to those advanced levels.

Answer (score 0):

While it is hard answering your question without seeing your `models.py` at least, I will suggest archiving the results. You can add a `boolean field` called `historical` which defaults to `False`. When an order is made you need to set the previous order's (or orders') `historical` value to `True` in your view set or function.
Here, `historical=True` means the record is being archived. You can filter on this `historical` column to display what you want when. Sorry this is just a high-level outline.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My problem is more about the Product changing than the order. So essentially, I want to capture the values of the Product as it was when the order was created so that even if the object in the Product table is changed, I can still display an order with the version of the Product at the time when the order was made.

Comment: How about adding a `JSONField()` called `extra` where you can dump the current state of the product into a dictionary? You can keep updating this dictionary as the orders change.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along these lines as well because I would find it easier to do a to_json() method on the Product. I was mainly worried about whether it would be better to create a duplicate object which will not be changed or to store the data from the model in a field of the OrderItem. Seems like both answers here suggest the latter.